# SharePoint Designer Installation Corrupt

Tags: sharepoint-designer

All, I'm having a difficult time with this one...

My **SharePoint Designer 2007** installation is *corrupt*.  SPD will not start.  SPD will not uninstall and it says "The Installation is corrupt."  I have Office 2010 installed and things seemed to work fine.

> How do I manually remove ***ALL TRACES*** of SharePoint Designer 2007??

*Note: I've tried the Microsoft FixIt and Office 20xx removal tools/scripts.  They remove everything except SPD and do not work... Also, it doesn't throw any Errors in Event Viewer..  :(*

I definitely don't want to reformat my computer for this...  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIXED :)**

Thanks for the input everyone!  I found a solution, however.  **The MSI Installer was corrupt!**  I didn't notice at first, but other products weren't installing properly either >.< !

1) I removed the old MSI installer in the */System32* directory by adding a ".old" at the end, installed the latest MSI and everything went smooth.

2) I also ran a utility called "Windows Installer Cleanup" and removed SPD Designer 2007 and SPD MUI.

**FIXED :)**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to correct the installation first?

You can run the diagnostic tools and try and repair the installation and then remove it.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/diagnose-and-repair-crashing-office-programs-by-using-office-diagnostics-HA001234076.aspx

If that doesn't work, this is the KB for manually removing office 2007 (which SPD 2007 is apart of):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218

Comment: @ Jesus, first and formost please forgive me. Okay thx. Now, above question says that I've tried the KB FixIt program and manual process. Although this might work, SDP Installation still fails. I will update the question.

Comment: I would manually check the items giving in the support article instead of running the script.  If its not interfering with your system, you may want to consider leaving it.  You could also try removing office 2010 and then try and fix the SPD 2007 installation, and then attempt to remove SPD again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help, but try to find the original MSI installation, right-click and choose repair. In same cases when an installation is corrupted this can help.

If I recall correctly SharePoint Designer is installed via exe file. In such case try to find the original exe and run repair.

Comment: @ Toni, when I do this it says, **"Error applying transforms. Verify that the specified transform paths are valid"**